# Extending disk capacity on root partition on VmWare, Ubuntu Guest

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, vmware

I want to increase my disk capacity on my virtual machine. I went on and expanded  8GB more free space from the settings. Now, I can see that part as a free space on my Ubuntu guest. I want to extend my root partition with this free space right now. I am following,

[This Knowledge Base Article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1006371?other.KM_Utility.getArticleLanguage=1&r=0&other.KM_Utility.getArticleData=1&ui-comm-runtime-components-aura-components-siteforce-recordservicecomponent.RecordServiceComponent.getArticleVersionId=2&other.KM_Utility.getArticle=1&other.KM_Utility.getUser=1&ui-comm-runtime-components-aura-components-siteforce-qb.Quarterback.validateRoute=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-navigationMenu.NavigationMenuDataProvider.getNavigationMenu=1&other.KM_Utility.getGUser=1)

Here, it explains how we can extend a root partition if it resides in a logical volume. I did follow up until step 9. I made my free space a Linux LVM partition and made it into a physical partition etc. Now, at step 9

> vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/sda3

I am getting an error saying basically there is no `VolGroup00`. This is expected since I didn't created my root partition as a logical volume. So at this stage, is there a way for me to extend my root partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VM isn't set up with LVM, then you just have to increase partition size and resize the filesystem.

You'll need unallocated space after the root partition (so it's either the only partition or the last one). If that's not the case, you have to move other partitions right.

1. Boot from Ubuntu ISO (any version, doesn't have to match what you have installed).
2. Run GParted.
3. Move other partitions if necessary (right-click → *Move*).
4. Resize root partition (right-click → *Resize*).
5. Apply changes using button on the toolbar.

Moving partitions will take a moment. Resizing should take a few seconds at most.

That's it, you're done.

Comment: Will this wipe the contents of the root partition?

Comment: If everything goes as planned, it won't. But partition operations always come with a risk - if you hit a software bug etc., data may be gone. Never happened to me though. Use your common sense and make backups if you can't risk losing that VM.